# How to reverse ReLU activation in deconvolution

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-network

I recently came across Matt Zeiler's deconvolution (reversing convolution) [paper](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf) . How is deconvolution able to reverse the rectified scalar output? From what I understand it sounds analogous to reversing the output of a linear / logistic regression model. How is it possible to go from a scalar to a vector?

Answer (score 2):

It's not reversing the ReLU, but applying normal ReLU activation again after max pooling and max unpooling.

It is used again

> "to obtain valid feature reconstructions at each layer (which also should be positive)"